# Mockito 'when' clause

Tags: java, mockito

I would like to create a Mockito 'when' clause for the following statement:

```
boolean emailEmUso = userRepository.findByEmail(userDtoRequest.email())
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(c -> !c.equals(userDtoRequest));
```

Is it possible?

```
when(userRepository.findByEmail(userDtoRequest.email())
      .stream()
      .anyMatch(c -> !c.equals(userDtoRequest)))
      .thenReturn(false);
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened? What did you expect to happen instead? Did you see [ask]?

Comment: You can mock the `userRepository.findByEmail` with data that matches your case `when(userRepository.findByEmail("testmail")).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList())` this will produce an empty stream therefore the whole statement will be `false` upon running the test. Similarly, for a `true` scenario you can mock a List that contains the `userRequestDto` in question.

Comment: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Boolean cannot be returned by findByEmail()
findByEmail() should return Optional
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

Comment: If you are mocking your repository, you should let the `.stream() .anyMatch(c -> !c.equals(userDtoRequest))` run normally, so that you have coverage of that code. Can you explain why you want to mock the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

When writing integration tests that require some form of mocking or stubbing, you want to mock as little as is necessary to replicate the desired behaviour.

Specifically, you do *not* usually want to mock any underlying JRE (or any other language) functionality (it is out of scope for your test and is not always easily possible). `stream()`, `anyMatch()`, etc. are library functions that have already been extensively tested, and your test should execute them as normally so that you can verify your correct *usage* of these functions.

The standard way to do this then, would be to mock the return value of `userRepository.findByEmail(userDtoRequest.email())` and let the rest of the code run as normal.

```
User user = new User(...);
when(userRepository.findByEmail(userDtoRequest.email())).thenReturn(user);
```

Comment: Smooth explanation, but i would add aditionally that no matter if UNIT or higher level of testing i would avoid mocking DTOs/Request/... Since creating a usual test data setup can be done easy and fast. 
Don't be that lazy. Use real data/dto and just mock external dependencies/calls (service, repo, clients, ...). That's more suiteable for real-world development at the industry.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I agree. The mock object would've made more sense if it was some kind of service class being returned by a factory, or similar. I've adjusted the code.